# How to create a time filter in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I want to ask a question related Power BI.

How to create a week filter which by default report should launch a time period selected in Power BI?

I ready created a

```
tID | Filtertext
7   | 1 week ago
14 |2 weeks ago
...
```

-values

[image]

in Power BI it looks like this
How I can use it as a filter and select certain period in report?

thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Relative Date slicer & filter feature built into Power BI. It can cater to all those requirements and many more - its easy and intuitive.

https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-desktop-slicer-filter-date-range/

No modeling preparation is needed - it is set in the report page design.

Comment: Ummm ... you dont need to.

Comment: And by using the relative date slicer, the staring date will be sunday, but I want a week starting date is monday and end sunday. so need to build own one.